# How to decode JSON arrays of API web-service in php

Tags: php, json

An API web-service is giving JSON output as follows

```
{
    "foodParameters": [
        "id",
        "foodName",
        "cerealType",
        "cerealName",
        "itemType",
        "itemNature",
        "itemName",
        "foodBenefits",
        "foodWarnings",
        "foodCalofificValue",
        "foodLifeDays",
        "remarks"
    ],
    "foodDetails": [
        [
            "12",
            "AAAA",
            "BBBB",
            "CCCC",
            "DDDD",
            "EEEE",
            "FFFF",
            "GGGGG",
            "HHHHHH",
            "300-500",
            "15",
            "NULL"
        ],
        [
            "21",
            "IIII",
            "JJJJJ",
            "KKKK",
            "LLLL",
            "MMMMM",
            "NNNNN",
            "OOOO",
            "PPPPPPPPP",
            "500-800",
            "10",
            "NULL"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I have written following code in php to retrieve the api values but unable to get any output. 
Kindly help in retrieving the json api data.

```
<?php
$foodName = "XXXXX";
$cerealName = "XXXXXXX";
$data=json_decode(@file_get_contents("http://XXXXX.com/food/foodInputGet.php?foodName=$foodName&cerealName=$cerealName"));
echo $data->foodParameters[]; 
echo $data->foodDetails[];
?>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You cannot echo an array, so try `print_r($data->foodParameters);`

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use [] for reading in
<b>/Users/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/food/fetchJSON.php</b> on line
<b>5</b>
<br />

Comment: now after adding print_r($data->foodParameters); I am getting following error <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'foodParameters' of non-object in
<b>/Users/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/food/fetchJSON.php</b> on line
<b>5</b>
<br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does what you were looking for

what I did was read the json and rebuild it in a readable format

```
$json='{"foodParameters": ["id", "foodName", "cerealType", "cerealName", "itemType", "itemNature", "itemName", "foodBenefits", "foodWarnings", "foodCalofificValue", "foodLifeDays", "osservazioni"], "foodDetails": [["12", "AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE", "FFFF", "GGGGG", "HHHHHH", "300- 500 "," 15 "," NULL "],["21", "IIII", "JJJJJ", "KKKK", "LLLL", "MMMMM", "NNNNN", "OOOO", "PPPPPPPPP", "500-800", "10", "NULL" ]]}';

$data= json_decode($json);

$result=array();
foreach( $data->foodDetails as $FD){
  $Ogg=(Object) [];
  $index=0;
  foreach( $data->foodParameters as $FP){
      $Ogg->{ $FP }=$FD[$index];
      $index++;
    }
  $Ogg = (object)$Ogg;
  array_push($result, $Ogg);
}
//print_r($result);

//1° object
echo $result[0]->foodName;

//2° object
echo $result[1]->foodName;
```

Answer (score 0):

invalid syntax
`echo $data->foodParameters[];
echo $data->foodDetails[];`

The above syntax is used when to set a variable.
`$tmp[] = 1;
$tmp[] = 2;
// $tmp == [1,2]`

You should do the following:
`var_dump($data->foodParameters);`
`var_dump($data->foodParameters[0]);`
`echo $data->foodParameters[0];`